# How to annotate the highest point of each line in the drawing?

Tags: python, matplotlib, drawing

How to annotate the highest point of each line in the drawing?
I attached the code and the image to clarify my question:

[image: img]

First: I want to add an annotate for instance point, star, or any sign to distinguish the highest point of each line in the graph.

Second: I want to assign the name of the line dataset to appear on the graph as a name of the line which drew on the graph.

```py
for i, j in zip(range(1,7, 1), range(1,7, 1)):

            j= np.genfromtxt(f"C:/Users/fadil/Desktop/Project/Segmentation/Exp2_29112021/CT&DCT/DCT/Similartiy Data result/file{i}.txt")
            plt.plot(j, markeredgecolor='none')
            plt.title('SSIM result DynaCT with result CT slices')
            plt.xlabel('DynaCT slices')
            plt.ylabel('structural similarity index measure (SSIM)')
            plt.legend(f"{i}", loc='best',fontsize='xx-small')
            print(i)
plt.show()
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: can you provide a toy dataset example (as text)?

Comment: file1  file2  file3 file4  file5  file6  file7                                                                           and each one contains  some numbers like                                   
0.9896089203675155
0.9839575480033408
0.9410503435692341
0.9258679570890237
0.9256026186354785
0.9268991263893254
0.9276794904186167
0.9302078990727014
0.92822151152344
0.9354903209849549
0.9268665202526295
0.9273717475578677
0.9300029656517599
0.9381356166211835
0.9344650002845617

Comment: I mean a small numpy array with dummy data, not files, and nicely formatted in the question

Answer (score 2):

To put something in the legend, the `label=` keyword is used while plotting the element. The legend is called only once, after creating all the curves.

`np.argmax()` finds the index of the maximum.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy  as np

for i in range(1, 7):
    j = np.random.normal(0.1, 1, 50).cumsum() + np.random.uniform(1, 30)
    j_max = np.argmax(j)
    plt.plot(j, label=f"{i}")
    plt.scatter(j_max, j[j_max], s=100, marker='o', facecolor='none', edgecolor='red', )

plt.title('SSIM result DynaCT with result CT slices')
plt.xlabel('DynaCT slices')
plt.ylabel('structural similarity index measure (SSIM)')
plt.legend(loc='best', fontsize='xx-small')
plt.margins(x=0.01)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: adding a legend and showing the maxima]